# Prometheus show top metrics filtered by number of labels

Tags: prometheus, graphite

According to this:
https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/instrumentation/#do-not-overuse-labels
i should stick to no more than 10 labels per metric.

I'm trying to write query which shows me top 10 metrics filtered by the number of labels they have.
Is it possible?

Comment: Actually a very good question, I dont have an answer :) however I believe that not the number of labels is dangerous, but labels with high cardinality (labels like IDs etc.). You can check it with the following query: `topk(100, count by (__name__)({__name__=~".+"}))`.

Comment: There is also a completed [PR](https://github.com/prometheus/tsdb/pull/369), which will allow to get all unique labels. Could be helpful in identification of high cardinality labels.

Comment: Thanks @mibrl! Looks like my understanding of cardinality is wrong. I thought its just a quantity of labels in a given time series.

Comment: you are welcome. Have a look also into this [GET /api/v1/label/<label_name>/values
](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#querying-label-values). You can get a list of label values for a provided label name. Could be also helpful in identifying potential problem.

Answer (score 4):

Prometheus provides [/api/v1/status/tsdb](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#tsdb-stats) endpoint, which exposes metric names with the highest number of labels inside `seriesCountByMetricName` stats. It also exposes other useful stats, which may help determining the source of [high cardinality](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/FAQ.html#what-is-high-cardinality):

- labels with the highest number of unique values at `labelValueCountByLabelName` stats
- `label=value` pairs with the highest number of unique time series at `seriesCountByLabelPair` stats

P.S. Other Prometheus-like systems may provide additional functionality for `/api/v1/status/tsdb` endpoint, which can help narrowing down the source of high cardinality. For example, [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) provides the following additional functionality:

- Ability to specify the date for the stats via `date` query arg. For example, `/api/v1/status/tsdb?date=2022-04-01` would return stats for April 1, 2022.
- Ability to specify the number of entries to return per each collected stats via `topN` query arg. For example, `/api/v1/status/tsdb?topN=100` would return up to 100 entries per each `stats` list.
- Ability to filter out time series for stats collection via arbitrary [time series selector](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-series-selectors). For example, `/api/v1/status/tsdb?match[]=foobar` would return stats for time series with `foobar` name only.

See [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/#tsdb-stats) for more info.